# Drools: Can Queries be invoked from the RHS of a rule?

Tags: drools

I have some code which invokes KieRuntime::getQueryResults() whilst processing the actions on the RHS of a rule, i.e. during the midst of a KieRuntime::fireAllRules()

This has generally worked fine for some time, but recently has started to deadlock under certain circumstances.

The stack below illustrates this (with some frames removed)

I am unsure whether this kind of operation, i.e. invoking a second operation on the KieSession from the same thread which is processing the first one, is supported at all - it seems reasonable that it would not be.

Can anyone confirm / comment?

Thanks.

```
"pool-1-thread-1@3924" prio=5 tid=0xf nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
      at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
      at org.drools.core.phreak.PropagationEntry$PropagationEntryWithResult.getResult(PropagationEntry.java:117)
      at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.evalQuery(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:895)
      at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalGetQueryResult(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:823)
      at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.getQueryResults(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:783)
      at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.getQueryResults(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:163)
...

      at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.innerFireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:431)
      at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.fireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:379)
      at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.fire(RuleExecutor.java:135)
      at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:88)
      at org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractRuleEvaluator.internalEvaluateAndFire(AbstractRuleEvaluator.java:34)
      at org.drools.core.concurrent.SequentialRuleEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(SequentialRuleEvaluator.java:43)
      at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:1067)
      at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1014)
      at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1006)
      at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1337)
      at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1328)
      at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1312)
      at 
...
```